# Elliptic Curve and Consecutive X Coordinates

Tags: elliptic-curves

My question is brief, is there an algorithm or method to calculate the consecutive X coordinates on an elliptic curve to find out if the distance between is constant?

The reason for the question is as follows:
   1. Base Generator Point is given.
   2. Embedding degree is given.
   3. The total number of points is given (N).
   4. For the curve, 1 - (N-1) are the multipliers for the points on the curve.
   5. The curve is half the full curve for X-Coordinates meaning 1 and N-1 are the same X coordinate but the inverse on the Y coordinate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is helpful, but there are a number of papers that discuss $x$-coordinates on elliptic curves that lie in arithmetic progression. Here's one paper:

A. Bremner, N. Tzanakis, J.H. Silverman,
Integral points in arithmetic progression on $y^2=x(x^2-n^2)$,
*Journal of Number Theory* **80** (2000), 187-208.

Comment: Does this work has any effect on Cryptography?

Comment: @kelalaka As far as I'm aware, the answer is no, there are no applications of the sorts of results tin our paper to cryptography.

Comment: I see, any possible applications?

Comment: Our paper has been cited 30 times in other papers (according to MathSciNet). You might take a look at those to see if there are any applications that you find interesting.